# Facebook app rejection due to general reason

Tags: ios, facebook, social-framework

I am developing an app which requires posting feeds to user's facebook page. This feature is achieved using Social framework and no facebook SDK is integrated. Account associated in device setting is retrieved and posting some data (link or text) to user feed.

When I created a new application in facebook for this purpose I saw a new review process. And I have submitted a review by uploading simulator build, screenshots and all needed informaiton. Today i got an alert from facebook that my app is got rejected due to some general reason.

'Your app does not demonstrate a real user environment or appears to be a test submission. If your app is in development, please only resubmit when your app details represent the full, real user experience.'

My application is in development and not fully functional. But I need facebook support in initial login only. I don't know what should be done next. Please help. Is there a way to contact facebook team for getting faster response?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's asking about app store submission issues, rather than programming, and is better directed at the vendor.

Comment: If you want to test the app you can add test user in it and when your app complete then submit it for review

Comment: You don't need to get reviewed to develop you app. Any user that have a role on the app you can ask for any permission even if you haven't been approved for that permission

Comment: @WizKid I have tried your option with the admin user who have created the app in facebook. But still I am getting an error "The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: Invalid permission: publish_stream". Could you please suggest what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Did you grant the app that permission?

Comment: I have requested for 'publish_strem' in app settings.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a Facebook App ID to post to fb when using the Social Framework, and therefore you don't need to create an App in Facebook. You just do something like this:

```
- (IBAction)socialSheet:(id)sender {

   // create Facebook controller
   SLComposeViewController *socialController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

   // add initial text
   [socialController setInitialText:@"Blah blah.."];

   // add an image
   [socialController addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"my_picture.jpg"]];

   // maybe even add a URL
   [socialController addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://my.cool.link.com"]];

   // present controller
   [self presentViewController:socialController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

To avoid errors, you can test if the service is available like this:

```
if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
   // user has setup their Facebook account in Settings, show Facebook option
}
```

-- UPDATE --

If you need to post to fb without presenting a form, as requested in the comments below, then you can use `SLRequest` which is documented here: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Social/Reference/SLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012234

Example:

```
-(IBAction)postMessage:(id)sender
{
    // fb endpoint URL
    NSURL *postURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed"];

    NSDictionary *postDict = @{
       @"link"    : @"http://some.cool.link.com/",
       @"message" : @"The message I'm posting..",
       @"picture" : @"http://url.to/my/picture.png",
       ... other key-value pairs that you may need, depending on your circumstances
    };

    SLRequest *postToMyWall = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST URL:postURL parameters:postDict];

    FacebookAccountManager* sharedManager = [FacebookAccountManager sharedAccount];
    [postToMyWall setAccount:sharedManager.facebookAccount];

    [postToMyWall performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
         // do something with the response or handle error
    }];
}
```

Comment: But my app is not showing any SLComposer. Actual idea is to share details in background without showing any composer view. Thanks.

Comment: @QUserS I updated the answer to address your new question